# Can't use sudo, gedit, i'm getting error in upgrading

Tags: sudo

```
sudo: unable to open /var/lib/sudo/username/7: No such file or directory
W: Not using locking for read only lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock
E: Unable to write to /var/cache/apt/
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

I can't use gedit and sudo. I'm was trying to edit the status file under /var/lib/dpkg but i failed to do so since it's a read-only file. And having gedit as root doesn't work. Since i was trying to fix the problems because i can't upgrade. I badly need help. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Use nano instead. login as root and then do a **nano /path/to/file** Have you tried that?

Comment: But from that error, Are you sure the file exists at all.?

Comment: Please do not ever use [Solved] in a title. Instead, check the box by the solving answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve it by booting to a LiveCD and running:

```
sudo fdisk -l
sudo fsck /dev/sda1
```

You will be prompted to answer a few questions. `yes` or `y` will suffice.

Comment: If this fixed your problem, you had a corrupted filesystem. Either you shut off incorrectly your PC and have been really unlucky, or your disk is failing. You should check it and have a backup ready.